# VS2017 + ICC 19.0: Failed to run MSBuild command

Tags: c++, cmake, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, icc

I am trying to build a C++ project using Visual Studio 2017 on top of the ICC 19.0 compiler.

This is the command I try to execute:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -T "Intel C++ Compiler 19.0" ..
```

This is the error I always get:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 2019-12-24 15:19:24.
    Project "C:\Users\user001\Desktop\myproject\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.14.props(47,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.cpp.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\user001\Desktop\myproject\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\Users\user001\Desktop\myproject\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "C:\Users\user001\Desktop\myproject\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.14.props(47,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.cpp.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\user001\Desktop\myproject\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.08


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I do have VS2017 build tools installed — and reinstalled several times, for that matter.

What am I doing wrong?

Why is it trying to use VS2015 build tools that I don`t even have?

[UPD:] The result is the same even when I execute this command from `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2017`.

Comment: Regarding error code [`MSB4019`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50497421/10155936)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari Seems to be inapplicable I`m afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after much chagrin I found out what was happening.

The ICC 19.0 installer misrecognized the version of Visual Studio and installed MSVS 2015 extensions instead of 2017, which led CMake to believe it should use MSVS 2015 build tools which were simply not there.

Problem solved.
All it took to solve this was to choose «Modify» from the ICC installer menu and switch to the right extension set.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.cpp.props" is exist.

If the project is ported from VS2015, Please check VisualStudioVersion parameter in your project file (.csproj/.vbproj), such as "C:\Users\user001\Desktop\myproject\build\CMakeFiles\3.16.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj".

[Visual Studio project compatibility and VisualStudioVersion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/visual-studio-project-compatibility-and-visualstudioversion/)